# Fully Convolutional Networks: Fully Connected Layers as Convolutional Layers

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm reading the paper "The Fully Convolutional Network" and I don't understand this passage in 3.1:

> Typical recognition nets, including LeNet [21], AlexNet [19], and its deeper successors [31, 32], ostensibly take fixed-sized inputs and produce nonspatial outputs. The fully connected layers of these nets have fixed dimensions and throw away spatial coordinates. However, these fully connected layers can also be viewed as convolutions with kernels that cover their entire input regions. Doing so casts them into fully convolutional networks that take input of any size and output classification maps.

How does this reinterpretation of fully connected layers enable the network to create classification maps? I don't understand this "reinterpretation".

The authors say instead of feeding the output of the convolutional part into a fully connected network which takes a flat, say 4096-dimensional, feature vector they feed it into further convolutional layers which then produce an output of dimensions 1x1x4096. To me this looks like a technical difference, how did we now retain spatial information?